# See the date last accessed a directory php

Tags: php

I was wondering if it where possible to see, with PHP, when the last time a folder was accessed. I was thinking about using 'touch()' in php but that's more for a file, isn't it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read This,maybe Useful : [DirectoryIterator::getATime](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getatime.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`fileatime()`](http://php.net/fileatime), which works for both files and directories:

```
fileatime('dir');
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know this information is only stored about files (According to others this is wrong and it is for directories - see Dinesh's answer). However you can iterate over each file in a directory and discover the most recently accessed file in the directory (Not exactly what you want but possibly as close as you will get). Using the `DirectoryIterator`:

```
<?php
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$accessed = 0;
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getATime() > $accessed) {
            $accessed = $fileinfo->getAtime();
        }
    }
}
print($accessed);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getatime.php

Comment: It seems to be stored about directories as well, both on MacOS and Linux. So just getting the directory's attribute instead of looping through all the files should be much faster.

Comment: @rid Learnt something knew... updated answer. I only suggested looping because I didn't realise that information was accessible via PHP

Comment: Well, PHP must use the facilities provided by the OS, so it will most likely use the [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/stat.html) system call, which is guaranteed by POSIX to provide `atime`, `mtime` and `ctime` among others.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [stat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) function

```
$stat = stat('path to directory');
echo 'Accesstime: ' . $stat['atime']; // will show access unix time stamp.
```

Comment: This displays the modified time. OP wants the time the folder was last accessed/read.

Answer (score 0):

I would open the folder and loop through the files (you can use `glob()` for that) and grab the latest edited time with `filemtime()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

i can post a small example if you still need help